# Adding .env vairables to run in for a given command

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, shell, unix

I have a .env file with variables in it like this:

```
HELLO=world
SOMETHING=nothing
```

I found this awesome script the other day, that puts these variables into the current session so when I run something like this

```
$(cat ./.env | grep -v ^# | xargs) && node test
```

Then I can access the variables in the `test.js` node file.

```
console.log(process.env.HELLO)
console.log(process.env.SOMETHING)
```

The problem with this is that that command puts the .env variables in the entire session so when I run `node test` without `$(cat ./.env | grep -v ^# | xargs)` after I run it, it will still have access to those variables, I'm writing a node.js test that accounts for these variables and I'd love to be able to run the same command with and without these .env variables without worrying if they are still in the session. Ideally I want to run

```
put-env-variables-for-this-command-first-command node test && node test
```

And have the env variables only be available in the test script the first time it runs.

Comment: bash lets you do specific `FOO=bar ./script` variables which sets the $FOO for the life of "script".

Comment: @MarcB How do I programmatically `cat` the contents of `.env` for the life of the script? Let's say I have 20 variables in `.env` I don't wanna manually write them in every time :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you access to the variables during the invocation of `node test` only

```
env $(<.env) node test
```

Answer (score 0):

I started using `foreman` for this which used to be bundled with the heroku toolbelt. It's not included anymore, however there is a stand-alone version called `forego` that works really well.

`brew install forego` on the mac.

Then you can use this to prop-up the `.env` variables into the current process.

`forego run ${ANY COMMAND}`

Examples

- `forego run babel-node index.js`
- `forego run node index.js`
- `forego run npm start`