# Setting variables with spaces within .env

Tags: bash, environment-variables, env

I have a `.env` file with a bunch of variables and I just came across an error.

One of the variables has spaces.

```
TEST="hello world"
```

So when I run this, [learned about in this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29355840/340688)

```
env $(<.env)
```

I get this error.

```
env: world"': No such file or directory
```

How do I set variables with spaces within .env?

Comment: You just need to quote the file contents: `env "$(<.env)"`

Comment: @glennjackman `env "$(<.env)" echo $TEST` seems to print a blank line.

Comment: @glennjackman, @ThomasReggi: This cannot work with the echo example because the substitution of `$TEST` is done before running `echo` in the current shell which does not have the `TEST` variable set. When `echo` is run, `TEST` *is* set, but `echo` does not know what to do with `$TEST`.

Comment: It should work for external commands though and may be more feasible than my solution in that case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your command is just a shell command, you could run your command in a subshell like this:

```
( . .env ; echo "$TEST" )
```

The `source` or `.` builtin has no problem with assignments containing spaces. It will set the variables in the `.env` file in the current shell's environment.

In the more likely case of calling an external program, you'll also have to add 'export' to each assignment in your `env` file like this:

```
export TEST="hello world"
```

This is necessary because `source` does not export assigned variables as `env` does, i.e. they are set inside the subshell only but not in the environment of another process started inside that subshell.

Comment: I don't have a `test.env` file I don't understand what that is. Let's say my `cmd` is just to `echo $TEST` so from your example  `( . .env ; echo $TEST )` does not work it gives me `-bash: world: command not found`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought `.env` was just the extension. I'll modify.

Comment: "The source or . builtin has no problem with assignments containing spaces" is incorrect. Un-quoted spaces will cause bash to think the word after the space is a command, that's why OP is getting "command not found". The values after the = need to be quoted if they contain spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Let me share my thoughts on that: (1) The space in the OP's example _is_ quoted, so my statement is correct in that context. (2) As I noted in the question comments, just quoting the command substitution would probably be sufficient in most situations, but it would not work with the example provided by glennjackman. (3) The actual problem here is that the quotes read from `.env` in the command substitution are not interpreted by Bash, then word splitting occurs, and `env` interprets the second argument `world"` as a command (`env NAME=value COMMAND ARG ...`).

Answer (score 6):

juste put the word that contains the space between " ".

Comment: If the value contains `"`, escape inner double-quote with `\"`. For example, `MESSAGE="Lets say \"Hi\""`